# How can I see when the computer rebooted? Remotely

Tags: windows

I need a way to remotely see when a computer rebooted. I have its hostname and am able to browse its file structure.

Would love to do this on Windows XP, Vista and 7 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the System Event log. Every time Windows boots it logs it there.

You can do this locally, you can do it remotely via the GUI (run eventvwr.msc, then Action, Connect to Another Computer).

You can also use PowerShell: In my $profile file I have this function:

```
    function lastboot([string]$computer)
    {
            Write-Host "Getting last boot time, please wait..."
            get-eventlog -ComputerName $computer system|?{ $_.eventid -eq 6009 }|%{ $_|ft timewritten,eventid;break}
    }
```

Comment: For Windows 7: The restart will show under source as "USER32" Event ID is "1074".

Comment: Yep, 1074 tells when/why it restarted, while 6009 is when it 'booted' after the restart.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using a wmi query in powershell:

```
$os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername "remote_computername"
$os.converttodatetime($os.lastbootuptime)
```